# TYPO3 TCA, hide tab in translated item

Tags: php, typo3

In my Extension I create several tabs for the backend with --div--, the code looks something like this:

```
    'types' => array(
      '0' => array('showitem' => 'sys_language_uid;;;;1-1-1, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource, hidden;;1,--div--;My Tab, title, category,
    ),
```

While there is an easy way to hide a single field in the translated item with: `'displayCond' => 'FIELD:sys_language_uid:=:0',`, I have no idea how to hide a whole tab.

Does anybody know how I have to write the 'types' array to hide "My Tab" in the translation records? Thank you in advance.

Edit (Solution):
Using config as stated in the answer is possible, but there is another way I discovered by accident: If you hide all fields that are associated with a tab with `'displayCond' => 'FIELD:sys_language_uid:=:0',` the tabs will also be hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need to use tsconfig.
Please check the section: "New content element wizard (mod.wizards.newContentElement)" in this link: http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsconfig/4.3.2/view/1/5/